# Getting error in swaggerHub Explorer when I'm hitting the API with server and with local its working

Tags: swagger

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47c6h.png)
Internal Server Error: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target | Time: N/A | Size: N/A

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVstU.png)